# apache camel for jira

Tags: java, apache-camel, jira

I want to build an Apache camel application to download a Jira
issue report, parse it, and store it into a .csv file.
I'm new at Apache camel, I do believe the jira here should be an endpoint, how to setup this configuration, I want to set is as from:("Jira") to (csv file).
I believe it could be something like this:

```
public void configure() throws Exception {

from("jira://pullRequestComment?ProjectKey=CAMEL-0000&IssueTypeId=1&IssueSummary=title")
.process(new MyLogProcessor())
.bean(new MyTransformer(),"transformContent")
.to("file:D:/camel/output");    
}
```

I tried the above code, I got an exception for java conversion type.

Exception:

Comment: This is the exception


"Caused by: org.apache.camel.TypeConversionException: Error during type conversion from type: java.lang.String to the required type: org.apache.camel.component.jira.JIRAType with value pullRequestComment due java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: spark/Response
 at org.apache.camel.impl.converter.BaseTypeConverterRegistry.createTypeConversionException(BaseTypeConverterRegistry.java:629)
 at org.apache.camel.impl.converter.BaseTypeConverterRegistry.convertTo(BaseTypeConverterRegistry.java:150)
 at

Comment: You may edit your post to include additional useful information. Comments are not well suited for that.

Comment: Your error indicates Camel has not found a way to convert from String to JIRAType. You need to do this conversion. Take a look at the camel documentation for this.

Comment: @SoucianceEqdamRashti, to be honest, first of all I want to make sure that I used the Jira endpoint in correct way, is it like how I used it ?

Comment: @SoucianceEqdamRashti
from(**"jira://pullRequestComment?ProjectKey=CAMEL-0000&IssueTypeId=1&IssueSummary=title"**)
I'm not really sure that the issue is in the conversion, I feel like the way is not in correct way

Comment: why don't you log the output and see what it says? add a log statement such as .log("${body}") before the .process to see what the exchange body looks and the type it has.

Answer (score 1):

The JIRA component returns Java objects from the JIRA REST API. You need to either:

1. Support passing in the object type to your processor class as a method argument
2. Convert the JIRA Java Object to something else, then pass into your processor

BTW- The JIRA component caches "seen" data to know what is "new" to pass into the route. For really busy JIRA servers, this looks and acts like a memory leak so you'll need to be mindful to manage that scenario

Comment: before solving the java conversion issue, I just wanted to make sure that this is the way we call jira endpoint, is the way I'm using correct.? in other words, what should I put in **from("                                       ")

to("                                   ")**

Answer (score 1):

The `pullRequestComment` endpoint is for a *producer* endpoint (i.e. it can only go in `to("jira:pullRequestComment?...")`. Since you want to poll for new comments, you should use the `newComment` endpoint. So your route would look something like:

```
from("jira:newComment?serverUrl={host}&username={username}password={password}")
  .process(new MyLogProcessor())
  .bean(new MyTransformer(),"transformContent")
  .to("file:D:/camel/output");
```

Note that this endpoint returns an object of type `com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.domain.Comment`, so in `MyLogProcessor` if you do `exchange.getIn().getBody()`, it will return an object of type `Comment` (or maybe a List if there are multiple objects, you'll have to test this).

If you want to post a pull request comment, then you can use the `pullRequestComment` endpoint like the following:

```
from("direct://some/uri/name")
  .header("ProjectKey", "CAMEL-0000")
  .header("IssueTypeId", 1L)
  .header("IssueSummary", "title")
  .to("jira:pullRequestComment?serverUrl={host}&username={username}password={password}")
  .... // More processing here
```

Then if you invoke the route `from("direct://some/uri/name")`, it should post the comment that's in the exchange body.